# Pandas finding average in a comma separated column

Tags: pandas, csv, average

I want to take average based on one column which is comma separated and take mean on other column.

My file looks like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
A, B, C 2.9
A, C    9.087
D       6.78
B, D, C 5.49
```

My output should look like this:

```
A   7.4435
B   5.645
C   5.83
D   6.135
```

My code is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.ColumnA.str.split(',', expand=True).stack(), columns= ['ColumnA'])  
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
df_avg = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by = ['ColumnA'])['ColumnB'].mean())
df_avg = df_avg.reset_index()
```

It has to be around the same lines but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution is created `index` by column `ColumnB` for avoid lost column values after `stack` and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), last is added `as_index=False` for column after aggregation:

```
df = (df.set_index('ColumnB')['ColumnA']
        .str.split(',', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='ColumnA')
        .groupby('ColumnA', as_index=False)['ColumnB']
        .mean())
print (df)
  ColumnA   ColumnB
0       A  5.993500
1       B  4.195000
2       C  5.825667
3       D  6.135000
```

Or alternative solution with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = (df.assign(ColumnA = df['ColumnA'].str.split(','))
        .explode('ColumnA')
        .groupby('ColumnA', as_index=False)['ColumnB']
        .mean())
print (df)
  ColumnA   ColumnB
0       A  5.993500
1       B  4.195000
2       C  5.825667
3       D  6.135000
```